# How to autoload html table based on variable in the URL (Python, Flask, Mysql)

Tags: python, html, css, flask, methods

Python-

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET','POST'])
def search():
    if request.method == "POST":
        classname = request.args['class']
        cursor.execute("select * from errordata where rule_name like %s", (classname))
        conn.commit()
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        data1 = len(data)
        # all in the search box will return all the tuples
        if len(data) == 0 and classname == 'all': 
            cursor.execute("SELECT * from errordata ORDER BY error_date DESC")
            conn.commit()
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            data1 = len(data)
        return render_template('search.html', data=data, data1=data1) 
    return render_template('search.html')
```

HTML-

```
<form class="errorboard" method="post" action="" 
         style="margin:auto;max-width:600px">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search by Rule-Name" name="book">
            <div>
               Total errors- {{data1}}
            </div>
        </form>
            <table> 
            <tr bgcolor="#000"> 
            {% for item in data %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{item[0]}} </td>
                <td> {{item[1]}} </td>
                <td> {{item[2]}} </td>
                <td> {{item[3]}} </td>
                <td> {{item[4]}} </td>
                <td> {{item[5]}} </td>
                <td> {{item[6]}} </td>
                <td> {{item[7]}} </td>
                <td> {{item[8]}} </td>
           </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

How to make the HTML table load as soon as I enter the URL, Now I need to click enter or a submit button for the table to load based on the SQL query (Value taken from URL).

Tried to remove the form tag and added the method = POST in table tag, But didnt work. It just goes blank with out a input box for me to submit or enter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: With the existing code, When i enter the webpage using the URL http://127.0.0.1:5000/search?class=<somevariable>, the table that I need based on the <somevariable> does not automatically load, But I will have to press enter button and then the table loads. How do I overcome this? 
What I want is for the table to automatically load the data based on the <somevariable> as and when I enter the webpage. I should not be doing any Enter button or submit button.

Comment: When you enter the URL it generates a GET request to your api. But you are querying the data only if the request method is POST.

Comment: Oh yes! thanks so much, Changed it to if request.method == "GET", Works fine.